# Unable to find Java page in Android Manifest

Tags: java, android

I was wondering why Android Studio can't seem to find my second java page called "LineDetails" It is able to use my first page called "CreateLine" - Could anyone help me as to why the second page cant be found?

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".CreateLine"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".LineDetails"
        android:label="Line Details" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: how do you launch your second Activity LineDetails?

Comment: just a next button on the CreateLine page using an intent

Comment: it should work also check under which package your have LineDetails

Comment: There only is one package, it wont recognise my LineDetails page in the AndroidManifest.xml but will recognise my CreateLine page both with the same package

Comment: You need to add more information. How do you start the second Activity. What is the error stacktrace?

Comment: try to gradle sync the project

Comment: Add your error stacktrace

Comment: tried gradle sync and no help, I just go to the next page using a next button in the CreateLine page ....

Comment: Check weather your file names are correct and still in the same package and same location where your first class is created

Comment: there is no errors apart from when I hover over "android:name=".LineDetails" it says ....... "'com.almac.tracker.LineDetails' is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity'"

Comment: Post your LineDetails Activity code. The problem lies there!

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.almac.tracker;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.line_details, container, false);
}

@Override
protected void createTracks() {
    setDemoFinished(false);
    final DecoView decoView = getDecoView();
    final View view = getView();
    if (decoView == null || view == null) {
        return;
    }
    decoView.deleteAll();
    decoView.configureAngles(mTotalAngle[mStyleIndex], mRotateAngle[mStyleIndex]);

    final float seriesMax = 50f;
    SeriesItem arcBackTrack = new SeriesItem.Builder(Color.argb(255, 228, 228, 228))
            .setRange(0, seriesMax, seriesMax)
            .setInitialVisibility(false)
            .setLineWidth(getDimension(mTrackBackWidth[mStyleIndex]))
            .setChartStyle(mPie[mStyleIndex] ? SeriesItem.ChartStyle.STYLE_PIE : SeriesItem.ChartStyle.STYLE_DONUT)
            .build();

    mBackIndex = decoView.addSeries(arcBackTrack);

    float inset = 0;
    if (mTrackBackWidth[mStyleIndex] != mTrackWidth[mStyleIndex]) {
        inset = getDimension((mTrackBackWidth[mStyleIndex] - mTrackWidth[mStyleIndex]) / 2);
    }
    SeriesItem seriesItem1 = new SeriesItem.Builder(Color.argb(255, 255, 165, 0))
            .setRange(0, seriesMax, 0)
            .setInitialVisibility(false)
            .setLineWidth(getDimension(mTrackWidth[mStyleIndex]))
            .setInset(new PointF(-inset, -inset))
            .setSpinClockwise(mClockwise[mStyleIndex])
            .setCapRounded(mRounded[mStyleIndex])
            .setChartStyle(mPie[mStyleIndex] ? SeriesItem.ChartStyle.STYLE_PIE : SeriesItem.ChartStyle.STYLE_DONUT)
            .build();

    mSeries1Index = decoView.addSeries(seriesItem1);

    SeriesItem seriesItem2 = new SeriesItem.Builder(Color.argb(255, 255, 51, 51))
            .setRange(0, seriesMax, 0)
            .setInitialVisibility(false)
            .setCapRounded(true)
            .setLineWidth(getDimension(mTrackWidth[mStyleIndex]))
            .setInset(new PointF(inset, inset))
            .setCapRounded(mRounded[mStyleIndex])
            .build();

    mSeries2Index = decoView.addSeries(seriesItem2);

    final TextView textPercent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPercentage);
    if (textPercent != null) {
        textPercent.setText("");
        addProgressListener(seriesItem1, textPercent, "%.0f%%");
    }

    final TextView textToGo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textRemaining);
    textToGo.setText("");
    addProgressRemainingListener(seriesItem1, textToGo, "%.0f min to goal", seriesMax);

    View layout = getView().findViewById(R.id.layoutActivities);
    layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    final TextView textActivity1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textActivity1);
    addProgressListener(seriesItem1, textActivity1, "%.0f Km");
    textActivity1.setText("");

    final TextView textActivity2 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textActivity2);
    textActivity2.setText("");
    addProgressListener(seriesItem2, textActivity2, "%.0f Km");
}

@Override
protected void setupEvents() {
    final DecoView decoView = getDecoView();
    final View view = getView();
    if (decoView == null || decoView.isEmpty() || view == null) {
        return;
    }

    mUpdateListeners = true;
    final TextView textPercent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPercentage);
    final TextView textToGo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textRemaining);
    final View layout = view.findViewById(R.id.layoutActivities);
    final View[] linkedViews = {textPercent, textToGo, layout};
    final int fadeDuration = 2000;

    if (mPie[mStyleIndex]) {
        decoView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(DecoEvent.EventType.EVENT_SHOW, true)
                .setIndex(mBackIndex)
                .setDuration(2000)
                .build());
    } else {
        decoView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(DecoEvent.EventType.EVENT_SHOW, true)
                .setIndex(mBackIndex)
                .setDuration(3000)
                .build());

        decoView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(DecoDrawEffect.EffectType.EFFECT_SPIRAL_OUT)
                .setIndex(mSeries1Index)
                .setFadeDuration(fadeDuration)
                .setDuration(2000)
                .setDelay(1000)
                .build());
    }

    decoView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(DecoDrawEffect.EffectType.EFFECT_SPIRAL_OUT)
            .setIndex(mSeries2Index)
            .setLinkedViews(linkedViews)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .setDelay(1100)
            .build());

    decoView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(10).setIndex(mSeries2Index).setDelay(3900).build());
    decoView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(22).setIndex(mSeries2Index).setDelay(7000).build());

    decoView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(25).setIndex(mSeries1Index).setDelay(3300).build());
    decoView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(50).setIndex(mSeries1Index).setDuration(1500).setDelay(9000).build());
    decoView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(0).setIndex(mSeries1Index).setDuration(500).setDelay(10500)
            .setListener(new DecoEvent.ExecuteEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEventStart(DecoEvent event) {
                    mUpdateListeners = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onEventEnd(DecoEvent event) {

                }
            })
            .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).build());

    decoView.addEvent(new DecoEvent.Builder(DecoDrawEffect.EffectType.EFFECT_SPIRAL_EXPLODE)
            .setLinkedViews(linkedViews)
            .setIndex(mSeries1Index)
            .setDelay(11000)
            .setDuration(3000)
            .setDisplayText("GOAL!")
            .setListener(new DecoEvent.ExecuteEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEventStart(DecoEvent event) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onEventEnd(DecoEvent event) {
                    mStyleIndex++;
                    if (mStyleIndex >= mTrackBackWidth.length) {
                        mStyleIndex = 0;
                        setDemoFinished(true);
                        return;
                    }

                    createTracks();
                    setupEvents();
                }
            })
            .build());
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't post it as an answer. Put this code in your question and update it. Also it looks like you have not declared the class name even.

Comment: Put Full code  here it seams you are using fragment if it is fragment than dont need to declare in AndroidManifiest.xml file

Comment: Yes as mentioned by @sushantgosavi if its a fragment it doesn't need to be declared it the Manifest

Answer (score -1):

> LineDetails is Activity? If yes than  if your activity path is
>   your.package.name.LineDetails than declare like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your.package.name">

    <activity
        android:name=".LineDetails"
        android:label="Line Details" >          
</manifest>
```

if there is one onther Package name added like this path  your.package.name.OtherName.LineDetails than

```
<activity
      android:name=".OtherName.LineDetails"
      android:label="Line Details" >
```

In short you have to give path of your activity after package name declare in manifest tag  `package="your.package.name"`

> *If LineDetails  is Fragment?* **than no need to declare this in your AndroidManifiest.xml file**

Comment: Thank you for your help, but they are on the same package...  anything else I could add

Comment: Please re-read the OP. Why are you directly jumping to the answer? From the comments it is clear that both the classes reside inside same package.

Comment: @ Novo Lucas  at the first line of my answer i add  the line LineDetails is Activity?  ...so before giving minus point just think... 

 LineDetails is fragment .....am i right Fionnuala?

fragments are not need to declare in AndroidManifiest.xml file

Comment: You are contradicting your own answer! Now you are claiming that it's a fragment which it seems to be. In the post he added as answer, it seems there is no class declaration at all. If you are  upset with the down vote I'll remove it but please show respect to other users. Downvoting my other answer won't help you my friend :)

Answer (score -2):

As we know, in android studio whenever we create activity through default template of activity it automatically add into manifest file. When your second activity onCreate() method is called check  all view instantiated properly or not.

Comment: I don't think its apt answer to the question. How can you tell the error without actually seeing the code of LinesDetail Activity?